# Heroku push rejected because of unrecognized error

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, heroku, buildpack

I just set a new python/opencv buildpack to my rails application on Heroku because I need it for the backend.

My Heroku buildpacks:

```
1. https://github.com/diogojc/heroku-buildpack-python-opencv-scipy
2. heroku/ruby
```

I tried to push a new commit, and got the following "unrecognized error":

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Fetching set buildpack https://github.com/diogojc/heroku-buildpack-python-opencv-scipy... done
remote: -----> Python + OpenCV + Numpy + Scipy app detected
remote: -----> Generating environment
remote:        Unpacking...
remote: -----> Creating environment variables.
remote: -----> Buildpack installed.
remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/ruby
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed due to an unrecognized error, and we've been notified.
remote: 
remote:  !     Please try pushing again.
remote:  !     If the problem persists, see http://help.heroku.com/ and provide Request ID 8593d083-4525-429a-8bf1-fd5d2deca0db.
remote: 
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to memfinder.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/memfinder.git
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: !     Please try pushing again.
!     If the problem persists, see http://help.heroku.com/ and provide Request ID 8593d083-4525-429a-8bf1-fd5d2deca0db.

Comment: Thanks but I pushed again but the same error appeared and I sent a request to the heroku support.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? What was the problem?